# Is there a generic word in English that means "through time"?

Tags: single-word-requests, time

I know "temporal" means "to do with time", but I'm looking specifically for a term that means "spanning time" or "over time". Not necessarily *all* time, as "eternal" would mean, nor do I want to necessarily imply anything about the span of time (e.g. being long or short).

Upon reflection, I guess "temporally" is actually the closest word to use. I was just hoping for a word that meant literally "spans time". I guess the implication of using the word "temporally", because it deals with time, also often implies over the course of time.

However to illustrate the difference, I could use the term "temporal locality" to mean things that are close together in time (a term we use in Computer Science). In this case, "temporal" refers specifically to the concept of time, not the concept of something spanning it (it generally refers to two points in time that are close together, and points in time do not "span" time).

**Update:** Here's a much better example, though it's specific to programming: let's suppose we deal with the concept of locking an object. We might say that an object is "temporally locked" which means that it is locked with respect to a certain time; but we might also want to say that it is locked *through* time. I'd like to be able to say the latter with an adverb such as "it is locked `_____`". Since temporally locked already means something else, we need a distinction.

I honestly don't know if such a word exists, and it's more out of curiosity than anything, but thanks to all the folks who have contributed ideas. :)

**Update 2:** I've thought of another way to formulate my request. Think of it perhaps as the opposite of a specific point in time. In other words, a word that means **"not restricted to a particular point in time"**. I think perhaps that's a better example than my lock example above.

I like the word *chronological* for this reason, but chronological also implies the concept of order and specifically *progression* through time, which isn't really part of this concept. *Indefinite* also works, to a degree, but as the term doesn't involve time itself, it would have to be *temporally indefinite*. This is very close, but again, a single word would be awesome.

Comment: You know, I think an adverb of time is unnecessary in your example sentence. To say that something *changes* is to say that it changes over time; without the passage of time, no change would occur. You can argue about the rate of change, whether it's slow or fast (relatively speaking), but you can't very well argue that a transformation doesn't involve the passage of time.

Comment: @Jasper Loy, Robusto is saying that "Change" normally occurs over time so there is no point in saying "over time" in your example "it changes over time".  I wouldn't agree with the point, however, because would the gradual change be considered change meaning that some change would be instant, basically, not within the span of any time?

Comment: Maybe such an adverb is not crucial in the example, but there are conditions where it **is**. I'm trying to describe _paleography_. I want to say that it's "the study and decipherment of handwriting in arbitrary languages and <through time>."The desired highlight is that the documents studied can be from any time period. (I use the word as in the FutureLearn MOOC, "Early Modern Scottish Pal[a]eography".) I like @Blougram's answer. Perhaps saying, "the study and decipherment of handwriting in arbitrary languages and diachronically", only gives me another abstruse word from ancient Greek ; )

Comment: However, it _is_ the precise word desired. Hopefully the person has picked up many descriptive words (in a large vocabulary), but simply hasn't run into _paleography_ yet. I guess if that were the case, my description could be, "the study and decipherment of handwriting polylingually and diachronically." Here, cf. [my current view of Wiktionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20230223022147/https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polylingual), the first definition: "of or pertaining to multiple languages".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'Diachronically' would stress that the action occurs through time:

"[f. Gr. διά throughout, during + χρόν-ος time + -ic.]

1.1 Lasting through time, or during the existing period." -- OED

Comment: I like that one. ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's a veritable smorgasbord of words in English describing something that spans a lot of time.  Amongst them are: *lengthy*, *long-lasting*, *drawn-out*, *long-winded*, *overlong*, and *enduring*.

If you want a word that simply refers to the fact that something happens over a period of time rather than forever, then *temporal*, as you mentioned, seems to me to be the word to use.  Here's a dictionary definition:

> **3.** enduring for a time only; temporary; transitory ( opposed to eternal ).

Example usage:

> It changes **temporally**.

As the definition says, there's also *temporary* and *transitory*.

I also just thought of *transient*, though that points instead to something lasting a short period of time.

Comment: No that's not what I'm looking for: I want something very simple, not implying that the span of time is long or short or anything else.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add *temporal*.

Comment: Hmm, I think "transitory" is definitely on the right track. Best one so far.

Comment: Yes I realize "temporally" would work in the example sentence, but it still literally just means "to do with time", thus the "over time" is implied by the use of "changes", which may have been a bad choice for an example.

Comment: No, I'd say *temporally* can indeed mean "over time", and in the adverbial sense I suggested, that is what I would interpret it to mean.  If you want to be exceedingly clear, then just say "over time".

Comment: @chaiguy: "Transitory" and "transitorily" are very definitely suggestive of things which only last for a *brief* period of time. Plus I do not think you can say, for example, "it changes transitorily". You can't really use "chronologically" in that sentence either, and it does have overtones of the *sequence* of events over time, but I think it may be the closest you'll get.

Answer (score 3):

I see that nobody has posted the most obvious (to me) alternative to *temporal*: *[chronological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chronological)*.

> 2. In units of time. [...]
>   **Usage notes**
>   In the "units of time" sense, the term is almost exclusively used to clarify a contrast.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use *duration* or *durational*.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this, but this is very good. There's a definite implication of transience (i.e. the subject eventually ending) but "locked durationally" vs. "locked temporally" is a good distinction of concepts!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Would [indefinitely](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indefinitely) work?

Comment: This isn't bad, and gives me an idea for a clarification of my request, which is that I'm looking for a word that means "not restricted to a particular point in time".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *perennially*?

> **perennial** |pəˈrɛnjəl| |pəˈrɛniəl|
>   adjective
>   lasting or existing for a long or apparently infinite time; enduring : *his perennial distrust of the media*.

Comment: The problem with *perennial* is it's most strongly associated with garden plants that die back and regrow over several consecutive years. The main other use, which I feel is effectively metaphorical, is as per your example.

Answer (score 0):

How about *chronic*? I know it's associated with illnesses and implies a long duration.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring highly abstracted metaphysical contexts, for something to exist at all, it has to exist for at least *some* time. Things that exist only briefly are [ephemeral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ephemeral), [transitory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transitory), or [temporary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/temporary).

Things that exist for a long time are [persistent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persistent) or [enduring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enduring). If it's important to emphasis that they remain *unchanged* through time, call them **constant, immutable, unchanging** or **durable**.

Answer (score 0):

You want "ongoing for some interval of time"?  I believe that *continually* fits well.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the word "eventually" as an alternative to "over time". "Eventually" does denote the passage of time. For example, "Over time, she learned to love him" can be restated as "Eventually, she learned to love him"

Answer (score -1):

"Temporary" or "Temporarily" refer to something that happens for a period of time, then stops.

A database object can be temporarily locked, meaning that it will eventually be unlocked.